# How to perform same grammar oracle query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I have a situation for data migration between Oracle and Postgres. Actually, it is not for data :D

In Oracle: `SELECT SEQ_A.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;`

I Postgres, I created a sequence SEQ_A. But are there any solution in Postgres that we can perform same query "SELECT SEQ_A.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;".

I have tried with UDT and added nextval inside, but it will be "`SELECT (SEQ_A).NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;`" (DUAL is a view) in Postgres (can't get value from a UDT without single bracket).

If you have solution for this, pls advise.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way you can find a built-in SQL query that works without change in Oracle or Postgres.  If you don't want to have different SQL queries in your application code, write wrapper functions in both DBMS. Then call that wrapper function from within your application code.

Comment: Thank you ! Developer should convert code from Oracle to PostgesQL. But they could not  modified code as built to hard lib.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PostgreSQL, but - in Oracle, `DUAL` table is one-row, one-column table:

```
SQL> select * from dual;

DUMMY
-----
X

SQL> desc dual
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 DUMMY                                  VARCHAR2(1)
```

So, if you're migrating **code** and don't want to modify all references to `dual`, perhaps you could create your own in PostreSQL (now that you know how it looks like and what it contains).